# Json working for certain vars but not for others

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've made a script that requests information via Json. For some variables this works just fine, for others it doesn't.

When I use `alert()` for the variable neighbour1 it says the variable is undefined, when doing the same for the variables number and colour it works just fine.

This is the request script:

```
function getcolours() {
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("GET", "camp_map_script.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                for (var obj in data) {
                    number = data[obj].number;
                    colour = data[obj].colour;
                    neighbour1 = data[obj].n1;
                    alert (neighbour1);
                    window["colour" + number] = colour;
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(number + ' ' + colour);
                    x[0].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
        hr.send(null);
    }
```

This is the php part:

```
<?php
include_once("../php_includes/check_login_status.php");
?><?php
$number = "";
$sql = "SELECT camp_id FROM users WHERE username='$log_username'";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$campid = $row[0];
$sql = "SELECT players FROM campaigns WHERE id='$campid'";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$players = $row[0];
$number = ($players*2)-1;
$sql = "SELECT number, colour, player, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8 FROM lands WHERE camp_id='$campid' ORDER BY number";
$query = $connect->query($sql);
$jsonData = '{';
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $jsonData .= '"obj'.$row["number"].'":{"number":"'.$row["number"].'", "colour":"'.$row["colour"].'", "player":"'.$row["player"].'", "n1":"'.$row["n1"].'"},';
    }
}
$jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
$jsonData .= '}';
echo $jsonData;
$connect->close();
?>
```

Also when I check the php document the variable n1 is echoed correctly. So the error must be on the java script side or the transit.

It is probably something stupid that I'm overlooking but I just don't see it. I've copy pasted the working parts and changed them to work with other variables but it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: What does console.log(data); look like ?

Comment: `console.log("neighbour1 is %d", neighbour1);` gives me ` VM364:2 neighbour1 is NaN`

Comment: what value did you get when you echoed row['n1'] in php? is it a string, number, whats the type? and since you are looping, is neighbour1 always undefined ?

Comment: n1 is a number. When echoing it is like this `{"obj1":{"number":"1", "colour":"red", "player":"ivaldir", "n1":"2"}`
And I define the variables somewhere else.